# Faster Prime Generation C#

Tags: performance, algorithm, c#-4.0, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I know there are many questions already asked on SO regarding the same topic but this one might be different. I have studied some algorithms for calculating primes from 2 to N. I have written the following algorithm to calculate primes within a range, say from `N` to `M` where M can be as large as `10^10` and difference between N and M can be `10^6`.

```
for (k = 0; k < t; k++)
{
    int[] indexOfPrimes = new int[m[k] - n[k] + 1];

    int index_1=2;
    int index_2=0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (index_1 = 2; index_1 < Math.Sqrt(m[k]);  index_1++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        for (index_2 = index_1*index_1; index_2 <= m[k];)
        {
            if (index_2 >= n[k] && index_2 <= m[k])
                indexOfPrimes[index_2 % (m[k] - n[k] + 1)] = 1;
            index_2 = (index_1 * index_1) + (index_1 * ++counter);
        }
    }

    for (i = n[k]; i <= m[k]; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            continue;
        if (indexOfPrimes[i % (m[k] - n[k] + 1)] != 1)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Here the loop with variable `k` is for processing `t` test cases. The algorithm takes lot of time to process largest range (i.e. 100000) when the m[k]>10^7.

Is there a way not to calculate from 2, but directly from within the specified range?

Is there a way I can make is faster?

Edit: Could somebody please provide me a random big enough input to test my algorithm. It always gives `Time Limit Exceeded`, however, it runs just within 2.5 seconds on my laptop.

Edit: I reduced it to 1.5 seconds at maximum inputs. Gives me wrong answer. Don't understand why.

Comment: Is this problem from SPOJ? From description it looks so.

Comment: Yes it is, I am getting `Time Limit Exceeded`.

Comment: your laptop just might be 6x faster than SPOJ computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest multiple of prime *p* greater than the bound *lo* is `floor(lo/p)*p+p`. You could use that for your starting point instead of starting from *p*.

Comment: It was wrong; I forgot to multiply by _p_. It's fixed now. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. your answer helped me to speed it up 2x. But I am still getting wrong answer, though, all my tests, however large they are, are perfect.

Comment: I'm not going to wade through your code. But if your answer is close, you may have an off-by-one error somewhere; maybe you're not marking the last composite in the range.

Comment: I have checked that also, can't find anything so far.

Answer (score 4):

From an algorithmic point of view, what you want to do is

- use any method to find the prime numbers between 2 and 316
- use those primes to sieve all numbers up to 100000, hence finding the primes up to 100000
- use the 100K primes to sieve the given range, hence finding the primes in the given range

To illustrate that last point with an example, let's say that we know all of the primes from 2 to 4, and we want to find all primes between 11 and 15. The first step is to find the set of primes between 2 and 4, i.e. `{2,3}`. Now we use that set to sieve the set `{11,12,13,14,15}`.

To do that, we note that 6*2 is the smallest multiple of 2 that's in the desired range, and then we eliminate all multiples of 2 until we reach the end of the range, so 12 and 14 are eliminated.

We then repeat the process with 3, eliminating 12 (again) and 15. The remaining numbers in the range are 11 and 13, so those are the primes in the range 11 to 15.

One challenge is to find the smallest *multiple* of a given prime `p` that's within the range `N` to `M`. You do that by dividing the low end of the range by `p` and rounding up if necessary. For example, the following code finds the smallest multiplier `x` such that `p*x >= N`.

```
int p, N, x;

x = N / p;         // integer division truncates, so x may be too small
if ( p * x < N )   // if p divides N, then p * x == N, 
   x++;            // otherwise we need to adjust x

Example 1: (N = 11, p = 2) ==> (x = 5, but 5*2<11, so x = 6)
Example 2: (N = 12, p = 3) ==> (x = 4, and 3*4==12, so x stays at 4)
```

Comment: My range is not static. It can be 10-100000 or 100000-200000 or 100000000-100100000. But I think I got your point. First, I should get `sqrt(n[k])`, right?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal  316 is the `sqrt(100K)`, and 100K is the `sqrt(10^10)`. The point is that if you know all the primes up to 100K, you can sieve any range up to 10^10.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to check divisibility of each of the numbers from 317 to 100k by each of the prime numbers in the range (2-317)?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal The prime numbers from 2 to 317 can be used to sieve the numbers from 318 to 100000. Which is equivalent to running a `sieve-of-eratosthenes` on an array of 100K and stopping when you reach `p>316`

Comment: So if my range is (10^10-10^5 to 10^10) which will have approx 10^5 numbers, I'll have find primes upto 317, then from 318 to 10^5, then use them to find primes between 10^5 + 1 to 10^10. Is it correct?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal Almost. Given the range (10^10-10^5 to 10^10), you first find all the primes up to 10^5, then you use them to find the primes between N and M, so (10^10-10^5 to 10^10). You don't care about any primes between (10^5 + 1 to 10^10-10^5).

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal So you need an array of size (M-N+1) that represents the numbers from N to M, and you use the primes up to 100K to sieve that array.

Comment: Could you please elaborate algorithmically? I am unable to understand clearly how to make use of recursion or any other faster way.